# Disable Console logging for "log4j2" via Java Program Arguments

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, jvm-arguments

I have a program setup where a Perl code invokes Java Inline snippet
The java itself uses log4j2 to print logs onto the console (there is log4j2.xml specified in the java classpath) with contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

  <Appenders>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout
        pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="MAINFILE"
      fileName="logsFile.log"
      filePattern="logsFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="36"/>
    </RollingFile>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>

    <Root level="off">
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
      <appender-ref ref="MAINFILE"/>
    </Root>

  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Which essentially specifies to publish logs to a "logsFile.log" and "standard output.

We cannot modify the java code or the log4j2.xml file to disable printing of logs to the console, because both of them are supplied externally and cannot be tampered with.

Is there a way to remove `Console` appender from log4j2 via Java program arguments, because that can be modified from inside Perl, it is essentially:

```
use Inline Java => <<'END',
    EXTRA_JAVA_ARGS=>"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
    CLASSPATH => '/home/foo/jars/',
    J2SDK => 'home/foo/java/jdk8';
```

We can pass arguments as: `-D<property_key>=<property_value>` in the snippet above.

I've tried the solution below:

1. Create a new log4j2.xml in some other directory and remove Console appender from it
2. add: `-Dlog4j2.configurationFile='<path_to_new_log4j2.xml>` to the program arguments.

This solutions works as it overrides the log4j2.xml provided in the classpath. But the problem is that it might require updating when a new log4j2.xml is supplied.

Requirement here is to keep the configuration from the supplied log4j2.xml and override it's behavior through Java program arguments to not publish logs to console,

Or less ideal solution: if logs level can be set to "OFF" via Java program arguments so that no logs are published to either log file or console.

I've tried using `-Dlog4j2.level="OFF"`, but it only works in the case when a log4j2.xml is not supplied.

Log4j documentation:

> log4j2.level => Sets Log level of the default configuration. The
> default configuration is used if the ConfigurationFactory could not
> successfully create a configuration (e.g. no log4j2.xml file was
> found)

Comment: Well the console is essentially stdout, so what about redirecting stdout to null?

Comment: we can do that via program arguments? as we cannot modify the inline java code

Comment: Again the stdout of the java will be the same as the stdout of the Perl so you can remove the logging statements from the collective stdout. Since each statement will be prepended with the same string pattern you might be able to pipe through sed and then remove just the logging statements